# apache nutch - how to change configuration of plugins via REST

Tags: apache, nutch

I'd like to change dynamically the domain filter configuration per job (for example - on seed url crawl only urls from its domain).

(I'm doing GET /config/default to see what's there to change)

Thing is that the main configuration only point to a file on the server - which I can't reach (in this case

```
"urlfilter.domain.file": "domain-urlfilter.txt",
```

so - how can plugins configuration can be changed via REST dynamically? or in more general how can I overrides those "pointed to file" configuraiton

Comment: What version of Nutch are you using ? As for 1.X you cannot change the plugin configuration dynamically, only the main configuration that points to nutch-site.xml can be changed via the REST API.

Comment: I use apache-nutch 2.3

Answer (score 2):

Use create config service of nutch REST api.
You can do something like this :-

**POST** config/create

```
    {
    "configId":"myconfig",
    "force":"true",
    "params":{
              "urlfilter.domain.file": "domain-urlfilter.txt",
             }
    }
```

And use this config for that specific job.